# How to change the appearance of Paypal buttons (like Feedly does)?

Tags: paypal, payments, widgets

I need to integrate a simple PayPal payment option on my website. It's for a single product (1 year of subscriber-only features on the site), or the option to purchase that product on an annually recurring basis (i.e. subscribe). The customer would choose Paypal, be redirected to PayPal's website where the payment would be taken, and finally redirected back to my site where I would presumably receive a "transaction successful" message, which I can act upon.

In fact, what I need is exactly what Feedly have done on their [Pro subscription page](https://feedly.com/#pro/navbar).

I've had a look at PayPal's Express Checkout option, but that seems to require that you use one of their gaudy orange buttons, whereas Feedly have been able to visually integrate their two payment options (PayPal and Stripe).

Which PayPal product should I use to achieve what Feedly have done?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Express Checkout is a basic checkout service and limits the design aspects. I don't know for certain what product Feedly use but you will probably find it is an enterprise grade product which allows Feedly to use whatever style button they want and simply add the required data to the link for it to work with PayPal.